# WPF - TreeView.FindName() problem

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, findname

How come TreeView.FindName() can find things added to the Xaml doc at compile time but not dynamically added at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the item, remember to call the RegisterName method on the TreeView. Just setting the name won't work.